# Android: how to scroll back to RecyclerView item, after item is edited and re-saved?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a RecyclerView list with CardViews that is working fine.  The CardViews are created when a user enters data on an input UI called ActActivity.  When the user later clicks on a CardView to edit the original data, the onItemClick method launches ActActivity again using the start method that captures the correct CardView item position in the Adapter.

When the user clicks on a Save button on the UI to save the edited data, the ActActivity UI closes and the RecyclerView list is automatically re-loaded (MainActivity) and the updated CardView is shown in the RecyclerView list.  My problem is the RecyclerView upon re-loading always scrolls to the top of the CardView item list.  I would like the list to return to the original CardView that was clicked on to be edited.  I somehow need to take the original item position in the Adapter and pass that back to the RecyclerView when it is re-created.  And I need to let the RecyclerView know that the position is for a CardView that was just edited not a new CardView.  Any ideas on how to accomplish?

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    ...
    void loadData(){
    SQLiteDB sqLiteDB = SQLiteDB.getInstance(this);

    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDB.retrieve();
    Contact contact;
    cursor...
    Adapter.addAll(contactList);

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position, final View view) {
        cardview = (CardView) view;
        ActActivity.start(this, Adapter.getItem(position));
    }
```

ActActivity.java:

```
public class ActActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    private Contact contact;

    public static void start(Context context){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public static void start(Context context, Contact contact){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActActivity.class);
        // From the OnItemClick method in the MainActivity the RecyclerView item
        // position from the Adapter is passed into a putExtra bundle that the
        // intent carries to this Activity.  The data is then copied in the onCreate()
        // below using getIntent().getParcelableExtra(). So this is to update an
        // existing CardView item.
        intent.putExtra(ActActivity.class.getSimpleName(), contact);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(layout.activ_act);

        // Fetch data from a parcelable object passed from the MainActivity.
        contact = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(ActActivity.class.getSimpleName());    
        ...
        // Update edited EditText lines to the data Model via contact
        contact.setDataInput(xEditText.getText().toString()); 
        // Update the data in the SQLite database.
        sqLiteDB.update(contact);
        ActActivity.this.finish();
```

Adapter.java:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Contact> contactList;

    public Adapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Logcat output:

RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.jdw.v53/com.wimso.v053.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2575)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                       at com.wimso.v053.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:370)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1184)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5082)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2565)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: did you tried to use stables ids? also how you are reloading data?

Comment: I have seen some RecyclerView examples use stable ids but I've never used.  I will research.  I updated the code above to show how the data is loaded in the MainActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start `ActActivity` class using `context.startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);`  as shown below

```
 public static void start(Context context, Contact contact,int position){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActActivity.class);
        // From the OnItemClick method in the MainActivity the RecyclerView item
        // position from the Adapter is passed into a putExtra bundle that the
        // intent carries to this Activity.  The data is then copied in the onCreate()
        // below using getIntent().getParcelableExtra(). So this is to update an
        // existing CardView item.
        intent.putExtra(ActActivity.class.getSimpleName(), contact);
        intent.putExtra("position", position);
        context.startActivityForResult(intent,2);
    }
```

once the ActActivity has finished saving the data, you can set the adapter position in the  result back to main Activity using `setResult(intent)`

and once you get the Result in `onActivityResult()` in your MainActivity, you will come to know that you have come back after editing, so then you can use this method to scroll to the position ,as shown below

```
    // Call Back method  to get the Message form other Activity  
@Override  
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
{  
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
    // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
    if(requestCode==2)  
    {  
        int position=data.getIntExtra("position", 0);  
        //do all your adapter resetting here for recyclerView
        linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, 0);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Ok so basically use setResult to let the MainActivity know that we have returned from ActActivity and not created a new MainActivity?  Also, I do want to use the adapter position to scroll back to the position not to some Offset position.

Comment: @AJW yes exactly, if you don't want offset,set it to 0

Comment: Ok.  What does REQUEST_CODE do?  And do I need to use?

Comment: @AJW give any integer value and in the onActivityResult, check if you got it back

Comment: Ok so should that REQUEST_CODE be the adapter position of the item that is being edited?

Comment: Interesting, I like it.  And I need to run the setResult(intent) in the section I have for when the user clicks the Save button which finishes the ActActivity?

Comment: @AJW yes exactly, before you call finish() method once you have done the saving related thing ,you have to create an intent with empty constructor, and set the position value in it and then pass it in the setResult method, and in the onActivityResult in MainActivity, load your recyclerview and then use the scrolltoPosition method

Comment: Very good.  Any thoughts on the other answer that uses a class variable and sets it to the adapter position.  It then later checks the class variable in onResume().  I'm not sure which one would be best so would appreciate any insights you have on that answer.

Comment: @AJW that is also one work around, but there is a chance that when your ActActivity is currently in front, and your MainActivity is in Background, your MainActivity can be destroyed sometimes, so in that case, you could lose the position saved in the MainActivity in variable, so it can give some weird results.

Comment: Ok.  And that REQEST_CODE can be any random number, correct?

Comment: @AJW yes, in the example above which i have provded, i have used REQUEST_CODE as 2, and that same value i am checking inside onActivityResult method

Comment: Got.  last one:  what is the "0" at the end of "int position=data.getIntExtra("position", 0);"

Comment: @AJW ,that is just a default value to be used if the intent does not contain any value inside the bundle for the key "position". just a safe initialization, you don't need your integer value to be set to some negative number if you have not passed any position back from ActActivity,do you ? :P

Comment: I don't need it to be negative.  I thought the position value is always positive and you said would be passed back to the MainActivity using setResult(intent) somehow, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133603/discussion-between-hasif-seyd-and-ajw).

Answer (score 1):

Do the following steps  - 
 1. Keep a track of the adapter position of the card (*clickPosition*) that the user clicked to edit. This you can keep via a state variable in the MainActivity.

2. When the MainActivity is resumed check if it was launched after a card edit and if Yes, call the api - `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(*clickPosition*)`

Ofcourse, this will work pertaining to the following conditions  - 
1. The recycler view data set was not concurrently modified while you were in ActActivity.
2. If it is a New Card or Delete Card action, may be the handling would have to be done in a slightly different manner

Comment: Ok, I will try.  I have working handling for New Cards and Delete Cards so all set there.  Can you provide a sample example of state variable and how to check if MainActivity was relaunced after a card edit versus new launched?

Comment: Create a class level variable on your MainActivity and initialise it to -1. Then on click when you are navigating to ActActivity, set it to the adapter position of the item clicked. When you navigate back to MainActivity back, check the value in the class variable (in your `onResume`because `onCreate` might not be called) and if it has a non-negative value, call the api i mentioned. don't forget to reset the class variable once you have called the API

Comment: Ok will try.  I reset the class variable back to -1, to reset the state, correct?

Comment: How do I set the variable to the adapter position of the item clicked?

Comment: In your `onClick` method, you can get the position of the item clicked.

Comment: Ok.  And the way to check if MainActivity was launched after a card edit is to check the value in onResume in the class variable is >-1 or !=-1?

Comment: Either is OK. do some trial and error. If you face some issue, change the code accordingly. Btw click position is always non-negative

Comment: Your suggestion appears very efficient compared to another answer using startActivityForResult().  I'm not sure which one would be best so would appreciate any insights you have on that answer.

Comment: In MainActivity I set up "int clickPosition = -1"  In trying to set "clickPosition = Adapter.getItem(position) Android Studio throws error and says "Incompatible types.  Required: int.  Found:Contact" which is my data model file.  Any thoughts?

Comment: `clickPosition = position`

Comment: Ah, I get it.  Ok that is set now.  Last problem:  app crashes on "recyclerView.scrollToPosition(clickPosition);"

Comment: p.s. the "recyclerView.scrollToPosition(clickPosition);" line was put into onResume();

Comment: Hey, you need to put the stacktrace. Also please do a bit of trial and error before seeking suggestion :)

Comment: Added the Logcat output above...I've tried 2 days worth of trial and error...no luck with anything and the Logcat seems to be just a general error report that doesn't provide any clues for how to solve.  If I can get the clickPosition to the Adapter I think it will work because in my add() in the Adapter I have this line "mRecyclerView,scrollToPosition(0);" and it works as expected to add CardViews to the top of the RecyclerView list.

Comment: I was able to solve by moving the scrollToPosition() out of the MainActivity and by referencing the RecyclerView variable from the Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do so, the first step is when the user click a card, save its position in your preferred storage option, then while reloading the `RecyclerView` you can smooth scroll to the particular position. To do so you'll need to create a custom `LinearLayoutManager` . This is how you do it:

```
    public class LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller extends LinearLayoutManager {

    public LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller(Context context) {
        super(context, VERTICAL, false);
    }

    public LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state,
                                       int position) {
        RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new TopSnappedSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext());
        smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
        startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
    }

    private class TopSnappedSmoothScroller extends LinearSmoothScroller {
        public TopSnappedSmoothScroller(Context context) {
            super(context);

        }

        @Override
        public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
            return LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller.this
                    .computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
        }

        @Override
        protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
            return SNAP_TO_START;
        }
    }
}
```

Then assign this to your `RecyclerView` and invoke `smoothScrollToPosition()` .

```
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller(context));
 recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

Comment: I am confused.  So if I have 3 CardViews on the UI and I click on CardView #2 which is right in the middle of the UI, I want the user to return right back to CardView #2 after editing and saving any data.  So the RecyclerView shouldn't have to scroll at all, just return the user to the middle of the UI.  I'm actually trying to prevent the RecyclerView from automatically scrolling to the top of the list.